# How to wait for GenerateTableFetch queries to finish

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

My use case is like this. I have some X tables to be pulled from MySQL. I am splitting them using `SplitText` to put each table in a individual flow file and pull using `GenerateTableFetch` and `ExecuteSQL`.

And I want to be notified or put some other action when import is done for all the tables. At `SplitText` text processor I have routed `original` relationship to `Wait` on `${filename}` with target count `${fragment.count}`. This will track how many tables are done.

But now I am not able to figure out how to know when a particular table is done. `GenerateTableFetch` forks flow file into multiple based on Partition Size. But it does not write attributes like fragment.count which I can use to wait on for each table.

Is there a way I can achieve this? Or maybe is there a way to know at the end of the entire flow if all flow files in the flow have been processed and nothing is in queue or being processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till NiFi add's support for this, I managed to make it work using `MergeContent`. Use table_name as `Correlation attribute name` and then use `merged` relation to `Wait` processor using `${merge.count}` as target. Refer screenshots if someone is looking to do the same.

[image]

[image: MergeContent processor]

[image: Wait processor]

Answer (score 3):

If you have a standalone instance of NiFi (or are not distributing the flow files among a cluster to ExecuteSQL nodes), then you could use QueryDatabaseTable instead, it (by default) will only issue all flow files when the entire result set is processed. If you have all the rows go into a single flow file, then the fact that the flow file has been transferred downstream is an indication that the fetch is complete.

I have written [NIFI-5601](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5601) to cover the improvement of adding fragment.* attributes to flow files generated by GTF.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks again for marking this as an improvement on Jira. Problem with QueryDatabaseTable is, it does not allow incoming relationships. And I have 100-1000s of table to be pulled.